# how to protect a 12 volt operating DC LED Bulb from 230 volts mains supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, mains, circuit-protection

I have made a DC Led BULB (7 watt) which is working on 12 volts input.
By the way its input voltage range is 12-48 volts DC (using BP 1601 regulator ic)
Now problem is that when i gave some bulbs to an NGO members.
Some of them tried to operate it on 230 volts mains supply.which malfunctioned DC LED driver circuit.
Now i want to protect this 12 volt operating circuit from ac mains supply.
I tried and failed !!!

I used bridge rectifier to convert ac to dc means 230 AC to 230 DC then i m unable https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-helpto step down 230 Volts DC to 12-48 Volts DC.

Any other way to bipass AC input!!!

like over voltage protection,surge protection,over current protection,short circuit protection etc...i want a extra protection which wrong input type protection."MAINS POWER SUPPLY Protection for any DC circuit either it is operation on 3.3 v or 5 v or 12 v input"

:-) Fixed the circuit myself.

Comment: Why is the bulb compatible with sockets of a type that would supply 230V AC?

Comment: because i designed for poor people in india.B22 holder for bulb is commonly available here in cheap rates.So some unaware people try to check that if its also working in AC holder

Comment: You can simplify my question.like over voltage protection,surge protection,over current protection,short circuit protection etc...i want a extra protection which wrong input type protection."MAINS POWER SUPPLY Protection for any DC circuit either it is operation on 3.3 v or 5 v or 12 v"

Comment: Good grief! Thank heavens it's illegal in EU to use 230V connectors for non-230V lights!

Comment: What about a polyfuse?

Comment: @ George How to use polufuse...! I want something which block AC Voltage and pass DC voltage

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that blocks AC voltage use a:

- [bridge rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge):To convert/"block" AC voltage to DC voltage
- [polyfuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse): Overcurrent protection after. Should provide some short circuit protection too AFAIK.
- [transformer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) To reduce the voltage.

Note: The order of these components is not entirely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add an inductor in series with a rectifier bridge at the AC side, such that it drops about 200V at 50Hz. The wire should be thick enough to not cause a significant voltage drop at DC. I suspect that the inductor will be bulky.

Do not use this with only a half wave rectifier (single diode), as the inductor might cause a huge voltage spike as soon as the diode cuts off the current.